# how to load HTML page in DIV on clicking menu items

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am developing a website in HTML,I have 10 different HTML pages. menu bar should be visible on each page...i.e. on div content below the menu bar should be changed...html page should be load into that div after clicking on menu item..

Comment: what is your question ? what have you tried ?

Comment: please add your html and css to your question.

Comment: Avoid using IFRAME as it is not SEO friendly, and have a lot of constraints such as cross-domain security issues.

Comment: A word of caution: Don't break the back button: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2076/back-button-functionality-how-important-is-it

Answer (score 6):

1. Build your full markup (with correct doctype).
2. Add jQuery to your page.
3. Wait for document ready.
4. Attach `click` event handlers to your navigation links.
5. Disable default behaviour of links.
6. Load desired page with ajax and insert received data to a container.

---

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Ajax Website</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#nav a').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var page = $(this).attr('href');
                $('#content').load(page);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="nav">
        <a href="page1.html">Page 1</a>
        <a href="page2.html">Page 2</a>
        <a href="page3.html">Page 3</a>
        <a href="page4.html">Page 4</a>
        <a href="page5.html">Page 5</a>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        Welcome! Use the menu to navigate website.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the name of the file you are loading please? Also, which link causes the load? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

JQUERY:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$( "#career" ).click(function() {
$("#content").load("careers.html");
});
});
```

where `#career:` is  the tab button
      `#content:` is the div where the html is loaded